# Python math.log function math domain error

Tags: python, math, division

Using the code below:

```
import math
-2/3*math.log(2/3,2)-1/3*math.log(1/3,2)
```

Gives:

> ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 import math
>   ----> 2 -2/3*math.log(2/3,2)-1/3*math.log(1/3,2)
>
> ValueError: math domain error

Where as :

```
import math
-.66*math.log(.66,2)-1/3*math.log(.33,2)
```

Works.

What is wrong with the first code?

Comment: If you're on Python 2, get Python 3.

Comment: This seems to be something with the version of Python you are using, out of curiosity which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is Python 2, right?

In Python 2, the `/` operator between two integers performs [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), leaving only the part to the left of the decimal point. So, in Python 2, your expression would evaluate as:

```
-1*math.log(1,2)-1/3*math.log(02)
```

From here, it's easy to see why you get the error.

One alternative is to import the `__future__` division operator which would act like you expect:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 0):

That will only happen in Python 2, where `/` is an integral division operator when between integers: `1/3` results in `0` — and it is not possible to use `math.log` on zero.

In Python 3, `/` is always a floating point division operator: `1/3` is `0.3333333333333333`. (Integral division was moved to `//`.) Thus, the posted code would not result in an error in Python 3.